# Why is static method synchronization in java not working?

Tags: java

I am trying to learn how is static method synchronization works in java. I wrote the following code and as far as I understand the value of 
staticId should be 30000000. But I am getting a different result.

Value of Id 1      : 29974370
Value of Id 2      : 29974370
Value of Static Id : 29974370

```
public class Counter {

    private int id1;
    private volatile int id2;
    private static int staticId;    

    public Counter(int id1, int id2) {
        this.id1 = id1;
        this.id2 = id2;
    }

    public int getId1() {
        return id1;
    }

    public void setId1(int id1) {
        this.id1 = id1;
    }

    public int getId2() {
        return id2;
    }

    public void setId2(int id2) {
        this.id2 = id2;
    }

    public static int getStaticId() {
        return staticId;
    }

    public static void setStaticId(int staticId) {
        Counter.staticId = staticId;
    }

    public static synchronized void incrementStaticId() {
        Counter.staticId = Counter.staticId+1;
    }

    public void incrementId1() {
        this.id1 = this.id1+1;
    }
    public void incrementId2() {
        this.id2 = this.id2+1;
    }
}


public class TestClass {

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    Counter counter = new Counter(0, 0);

    Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            for (int i = 0; i <= 9999999; i++) {
                counter.incrementId1();
                counter.incrementId2();
                Counter.incrementStaticId();
            }

        }
    });

    Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            for (int i = 0; i <= 9999999; i++) {
                counter.incrementId2();
                counter.incrementId1();
                Counter.incrementStaticId();
            }
        }
    });

    Thread t3 = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            for (int i = 0; i <= 9999999; i++) {
                counter.incrementId1();
                Counter.incrementStaticId();
                counter.incrementId2();
            }
        }
    });

    t1.start();
    t2.start();
    t3.start();

    t1.join();
    t2.join();
    t3.join();

    System.out.println("Value of Id 1      : " + counter.getId1());
    System.out.println("Value of Id 2      : " + counter.getId1());
    System.out.println("Value of Static Id : " + counter.getId1());

    }
}
```

Output:

```
Value of Id 1      : 29974370
Value of Id 2      : 29974370
Value of Static Id : 29974370
```

Comment: If your output isn't what you think it should be, checjk you're actually outputting what you think you are. ```System.out.println("Value of Static Id : " + counter.getId1());```

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html

Answer (score 2):

1. You're not printing the staticId,
2. `getStaticId` and `setStaticId` should also be synchronized (as well as all the other methods.)

Comment: why should get and set be synchronized? Don't you mean incrementId1 and incrementId2?

Comment: @luk2302 all the methods should be `synchronized`, but he was asking about `staticId`.